# showing a simple identity $ \nabla^2 = . . . . $

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-analysis

I have my blank papers out and I am planning on showing that

$\displaystyle{\nabla^2 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\dfrac{\partial\left(\sqrt{|g|} g^{kl} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial u^l}\right)}{\partial u^k}}$

It would be nice if someone can sprinkle hints on how to go about this, or perharps just show this.

Ok, off to try and see if I can do this. Hoping for responses.

Comment: Start with the [Voss-Weyl formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260519/568204), and then apply it to the special case where the vector field is the metric-gradient of a function.

Comment: This is only true on scalars. For example,$$\begin{align}\nabla^2V^a-\frac{\partial_b(\sqrt{|g|}g^{bc}\partial_cV_a)}{\sqrt{|g|}}&=g^{bc}(\partial_c\Gamma_{be}^a+\Gamma_{cd}^a\Gamma_{be}^d-\Gamma_{bc}^d\Gamma_{de}^a)V^e\\&+(g^{bf}(\Gamma_{bg}^a-\delta_g^a\Gamma_{be}^e)-g^{bc}\delta_g^a\Gamma_{bc}^f-\delta_g^a\partial_bg^{bf})\partial_fV^g.\end{align}$$

Comment: What is $\nabla^2$ here? If $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian $\text{div} \circ \text{grad}$, then you can get the formula by integrating by parts against a test function.